# Gravity Form using shortcodes in a fields default value - Gravity Count (Gravity Entries Count) - Custom Conditional Logic for Notifications

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, inventory, gravityforms, product-quantity

We are using the **[Gravity Count](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravitywp-count/)** plugin. We usually dominate all its features. Some features do not meet requests.

**Here is a shortcode we use as an example:**

[gravitywp_count formid='4' filter_field2='162' filter_value2='SAMSUNGGALAXYS22' filter_field='133' filter_value='1']

We want to do this. SAMSUNGGALAXYS22 sends an email if the total stock count is less than 10.

We can partially do this with Conditional Logic for Notifications. But we need some data.

That is, SAMSUNGGALAXYS22 is able to get the sum of all inputs to the "Conditional Logic for Notifications" field as a value.

**For example entries:**

1 NUMBER ENTRY SAMSUNGGALAXYS22 QUANTITY 10
2 NUMBER ENTRY SAMSUNGGALAXYS22 QUANTITY 25

With Gravity Count Shortcode Total: 25 Quantity

I want to get the number "25" here as a value continuously in the Conditional Logic for Notifications value.

How can we do this? Do I need to write a custom function?

**OR**

Is it possible to use this shortcode in the value field in the Conditional Logic for Notifications field? If possible, how do we do it?